# How to wait for some second before next line executed

Tags: c#, delay, web-controls

I want to show a MessageBox right **after** the webpage is completely loaded in my Winforms WebControl.

I used this code to delay:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
Task.Delay(2000);
```

None of these is working. The problem is I got an infinite loop.

Can someone give me a solution or any better alternatives (if any) ?

Here is my code

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string WebPage = txtURL.Text.Trim();
        Webcntrl.Navigate(WebPage);   // Webcntrl is Name of  webcontrol in my  Windows Applications

        while (Webcntrl.ReadyState.ToString() != "Complete")
        {
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
            //Task.Delay(2000);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("hI ! website loaded Sucessfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

as per  Ahmed ilyas suggested I modified code as per below

```
 private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string WebPage = txtURL.Text.Trim();
                Webcntrl.Navigate(WebPage);   // Webcntrl is Name of  webcontrol in my  Windows Applications

                Webcntrl.DocumentCompleted +=new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(SiteLoaded);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }


        }

        private void SiteLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hI ! website loaded Sucessfully");         

        }
```

But now ,  message pop up multiple times.

Comment: "but both of not working" is not a good description of your problem. What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: you should be using the web browsers control's documentcomplete event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, `Task.Delay(2000)` will not actually result in your code waiting unless you call it as `await Task.Delay(2000)` or `Task.Delay(2000).Wait()`

Answer (score 1):

you should be using the Web browser control's documentcomplete event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx

this notifies you when the page has been finished loading. What you are doing is going into a while loop and holding up the thread that the browser control is executing on therefore nothing will "work" even when you put in a thread sleep (which BTW is not recommended to do regardless)

Comment: i modified my Question please check .. i use method wat u suggest me , its work fine , but in some URL message pop ups  multiple time means it goes multiple time in SiteLoaded function

Comment: Firstly, you need to subscribe to the event first before navigating - its better practice otherwise you maybe late in receiving notification. secondly, it could be some websites are navigating or have multiple navigations on their site in which case the event will be raised multiple times - nothing can be done about this. Did you also inspect what the eventhandler argument contains and see if that works for you? (the "e" parameter)